# Trouble reading Application Settings in Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

This is my first crack at creating an Azure App Function.  I've got it working when running on my local dev machine. Now I've deployed it into Azure, and I'm attaching the debugger to it (very cool, btw!).

When running on my localhost, I can use the `local.settngs.json` file for all of the app settings. That works fine.  But I seem to be hitting a roadblock on the simple process of accessing application settings when running the function remotely in Azure.

First (and this is a battle I will fight later) I'm sure there is a way to auto-populate the settings in the Azure Function based on what's in `local.settngs.json`, but for now, I added them all manually.

[image]

For now, let's just take a look at the setting `StorageConnectionString` who's value looks like this:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; AccountName=[redacted]; AccountKey=[redacted]; EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

[image]

All three of these attempts to get the value work on my localhost, but all three also fail when debugging in the remote Azure function:

```
string storageConString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

string storageConString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");

string storageConString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageConnectionString");
```

In all cases, I get this this error:

Error message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: itemName

Stack Trace:

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(String paramName, String value) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\CommonUtility.cs:line 143 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(String itemName) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\File\CloudFileDirectory.Common.cs:line 224 at XXXXXXX.Common.AzureFunctions.ProcessInbound.DoBooksExist(BookSource bookSource) at XXXXXXX.Common.AzureFunctions.ProcessInbound.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)

The error has me kind of stumped, as it doesn't even seem to apply.  Why, for example, is it calling `GetDirectoryReference(String itemName)`?

Answer (score 0):

> To get an environment variable or an app setting value, use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, as shown in the following code example:

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

> App settings can be read from environment variables both when developing locally and when running in Azure. When developing locally, app settings come from the `Values` collection in the *local.settings.json* file. In both environments, local and Azure, `GetEnvironmentVariable("<app setting name>")` retrieves the value of the named app setting. For instance, when you're running locally, "My Site Name" would be returned if your *local.settings.json* file contains `{ "Values": { "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "My Site Name" } }`.
>   Or you can use [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables):

Taken from [Azure Functions C# developer reference - Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got this figured out.  The core of the issue is some strange behavior on how the debugger works when attached remotely.  I finally figured out the real issue by setting the Publish Configuration to Debug before publishing:

[image]

The problem had been that when I had it set to "Release", the debugger would break on the first line of the method that had the error in it, and NOT on the actual line with the error.  This lead me to think I was getting the error on a line that was not, actually, throwing the error.

Once I knew the true line that was throwing the error, solving it was a snap.